# Error of Linear vs. Non-Linear Least Mean Square

Tags: probability

Consider:

- unknown random variable $\Theta$
- observed random variable $X$

The best Least Mean Square estimate $\hat{\Theta}$ you can get for $\Theta$ under the Mean Squared Error Criteria $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\Theta} - \Theta)^2|X]$ is
$$\hat{\Theta}=\mathbb{E}[\Theta|X]$$
This corresponds to the best possible error of $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\Theta} - \Theta)^2|X]=Var(\Theta|X)$. However, the best Linear Least Mean Square estimate is
$$\hat{\Theta}_L= \mathbb{E}[\Theta] + \rho\frac{\sigma_{\Theta}}{\sigma_{X}}(X-\mathbb{E}[X])$$
which results in error $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\Theta}_L - \Theta)^2]=(1-\rho^2)Var(\Theta)$, where $\rho$ is the correlation coffecient between $X$ and $\Theta$.

This doesn't make sense to me because $\hat{\Theta}=h(X)=\mathbb{E}[\Theta|X]$ is the optimal estimator for the Mean Squared Error, but $\hat{\Theta}=f(X)=\mathbb{E}[\Theta] + \rho\frac{\sigma_{\Theta}}{\sigma_{X}}(X-\mathbb{E}[X])$ can go down to $0$ when $|\rho|=1$, meaning that the Linear Least Means Square estimator can be better than the regular Least Means Square? I'm very confused.

The only explanation I can of is that $Var(\Theta|X)=0$ when $|\rho|=1$. That still confused me because then that means $Var(\Theta) = Var(\Theta|X) = 0$?

Comment: When $\rho=1, \hat{\Theta}=X$.

Comment: Hmmmm - good point. Well, when $\rho = .95$, $\hat{\Theta} \neq X$ but $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\Theta}_L-\Theta)^2] < Var(\Theta)$, which still contradicts that $g(X)=Var(\Theta|X)$ is the best possible estimate.

Comment: $Var(\Theta)$ and $Var(\Theta|X)$ are not the same thing. $Var(\Theta)$ is the variance of $\Theta$ without knowing $X$. Once $X$ is known, $Var(\Theta|X)$ is much smaller.